# Change wording of admin menu item?

Tags: plugins, admin

I'm using the plugin [Jigoshop](http://www.jigoshop.com) and I'd like to change the wording of the admin menu to something other than "Products":

[image]

How can I do this? What files need editing?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Inside the plugin folder check for File: jigoshop_taxonomy.php
Line no: 120

You will see

```
register_post_type( "product",
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'              => __( 'Products', 'jigoshop' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Products', 'jigoshop' ),
            'add_new'           => __( 'Add Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'edit'              => __( 'Edit', 'jigoshop' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'new_item'          => __( 'New Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'view'              => __( 'View Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'view_item'         => __( 'View Product', 'jigoshop' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Products', 'jigoshop' ),
            'not_found'         => __( 'No Products found', 'jigoshop' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'No Products found in trash', 'jigoshop' ),
            'parent'            => __( 'Parent Product', 'jigoshop' )
        ),
        'description'        => __( 'This is where you can add new products to your store.', 'jigoshop' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=> false,
        'hierarchical'       => false, // Hierarchial causes a memory leak http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15459
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug'=> $product_base, 'with_front'=> false, 'feeds'=> $base_slug ),
        'query_var'          => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'excerpt',/*, 'page-attributes'*/ ),
        'has_archive'        => $base_slug,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
    )
);
```

Update it as needed.

Comment: Note: editing plugin files directly is not recommended. Changes are lost during a plugin update.

Comment: @Geert thanks for the note. You could rename the "Plugin Name" to avoid such loss. However you are going to lose new features if you do so.

Comment: Providing a custom translation for "Products" by loading an extra mo-file would be a better solution, but it would update "Products" everywhere throughout the shop.

Comment: _"However you are going to lose new features if you do so."_ If you don't rename (or change the version number of) the plugin, you're going to lose your own "new feature". If you suggest that that shouldn't be done either the "solution" is neither good nor permanent. If you'd pin the version it's only not good, but at least permanent. @Geert is completely right here. -1

Answer (score 7):

As has been note by Geert, you should not edit plug-in files: changes will be overridden with an update (... and you really should be keeping your plug-ins up to date...). The best thing to do is...

**Ask the plug-in developers to add a hook to filter the label**

For *now* however you can do one of two things:

- Use a hook for when the post type is registered to update post type object
- Take advantage of the fact the label is translatable

#### Method 1:

```
add_action('registered_post_type','wpse54367_alter_post_type',10,2);

function wpse54367_alter_post_type($post_type, $args){
     if( $post_type != 'product' )
         return;

     //Get labels and update them 
     $labels = get_post_type_labels( get_post_type_object( $post_type ) );
     $labels->name = 'Some things';
     $labels->singular_name= 'Some thing';

     //update args
     $args->labels = $labels;
     $args->label = $labels->name;

     //update post type
     global $wp_post_types;
     $wp_post_types[$post_type] = $args;
}
```

#### Method 2:

since the label is 'translatable' you can use the `gettext` filter.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', '54367_change_label', 10, 2 );

function wpse51861_change_help_text( $translation, $text ) {

if ( $text == 'Products' )
    return __('Something else','jigoshop');

return $translation;
}
```

Comment: +1 for hooks. Am using the gettext filter here and there as well - not the cleanest, but nice to have for simple UI text fixes. @Teamworksdesign, this is *by far* the best answer and should be marked as correct, imho.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin.

Comment: D'oh, I've actually had that plugin for ages but didn't know you could rename things with it!!

Answer (score 0):

While [Stephen’s answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54376/4936) is a great way to work with the current situation, a cleaner solution would exist if the plugin developers made a simple change.

---

**Action to be taken by the plugin developers:**

First of all, when registering a post type you should set [the `menu_name` label](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments). This label is specifically used for the menu; if it’s not set the `name` label is used by default.

When setting the `menu_name` label, the [`_x()` translation function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) should be used. That way translators can supply a specific translation just for the menu name. Otherwise, the translation for 'Products' would apply to the normal `name` label as well.

```
register_post_type('product', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'      => __( 'Products', 'jigoshop' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Products', 'Admin menu name', 'jigoshop' ),
        // ...
```

Update: I opened a [pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/1129) for these changes in WooCommerce. Jigoshop’s code is probably very similar.

---

**Action to be taken by the plugin user:**

Load a custom translation mo-file with a specific translation for the menu name string. In your po-file the entry would look like this:

```
msgctxt "Admin menu name"
msgid "Products"
msgstr "My Productzz"
```

To load a custom translation file you can [hook into the `load_textdomain()` function](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way). A well-built plugin would also allow you to drop custom translation files into the `wp-content/languages/{plugin_name}/` directory. [WooCommerce allows this](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/6155ded5db141142cd0e9fc49a7158bd54c9feec), I’m not sure about Jigoshop.